# Python vs Powershell for collapsing long directory path into short

Tags: python, powershell

Recently, I downloaded a large online dataset (approx. 12 Terabytes size) and it has dummy intermediate folders as shown in the left-side of the following figure.

I want to remove (collapse) all intermediate folders as in the right-side of the figure below:

[image: Data hierarchy]

Method 1) I might try the following python script (using shutil.move) to remove intermediate folders.

```
import shutil
import glob   
source_path = 'C:\downloaded_data\01\001\2022_01'
moving_folders = glob.glob(source_path + "\*")
dest_path = 'C:\downloaded_data'

for item in moving_folders:
     shutil.move(item, dest_path)
```

Method 2) I might also use the following Powershell command:

```
Get-ChildItem –Path C:\downloaded_data\01\001\2022_01\* | Move-Item -Destination C:\downloaded_data
```

Are both method 1 & 2 simply based on copying/deleting operations for all files? Can anyone comment which one is faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both methods should be fast, given that you're moving folders inside a given directory tree and thereby definition on the same volume. Doing so doesn't require *copying* of files, just "hooking up" the existing directories to a different parent directory.

If you're running from PowerShell already, the PowerShell solution is likely (a bit) faster, because you don't have the overhead of creating a Python child process.

I suggest reformulating the PowerShell command as follows:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Directory –LiteralPath C:\downloaded_data\01\001\2022_01 | 
  Move-Item -Destination C:\downloaded_data
```

- `-Directory` limits matching to directories.
- The unnecessary trailing `\*` was removed, given that [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) *implicitly* enumerates the *children* of the given target path (assuming it is a directory). `-LiteralPath` specifies that the given path is to be interpreted *literally* rather than as a [wildcard expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards).